# Python Pandas DataFrame User Defined Function Transformations

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, user-defined-functions, data-wrangling

I have several DataFrames which I am in the process of cleaning the data. The following code works independently (outside of a function), however, I have to apply it to many DataFrames and want to clean this process via a user defined function.
Can you please help to fix the following so that it can be used for all of my dataframes.

```
def format_df(df):
    df.columns = df.columns.str
    df.dropna(thresh=1, axis='columns',inplace = True)
    df.dropna(thresh=80,axis=0,inplace = True)    
    df.columns = df.iloc[0]
    df = df.iloc[1:].reset_index(drop=True)
    df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(' ','',regex=False)
    df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('($)','',regex=False)
    df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('(Y/N)','Flag',regex=False)
    df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('(x)','',regex=False)
    df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('-','',regex=False)
    return df
```

Comment: can you explain what sort of error you are getting?

Comment: If you want it to be user defined then you must use `Object oriented Programming` for this.

Comment: @DevenRamani I get the following error codes when trying to use the function.
input >> format_df(WholeLoan_df)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_37984/3549822765.py in <module>
----> 1 format_df(WholeLoan_df)

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_37984/3706301082.py in format_df(df)
      1 def format_df(df):
      2     # df = input()
----> 3     df.columns = df.columns.str
   ....

Comment: The line `df.columns = df.columns.str` is not going to run because `df.columns.str` is a string method and df.columns is an index. perhaps you meant `df.columns = df.columns.astype(str)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `df.columns = df.columns.str` is not going to run because df.columns.str is a string method and df.columns is an index. Instead you can use the [astype](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) method:

```
df.columns = df.columns.astype(str)
```

Comment: Hey, When I try to apply this function to a similar dataframe I get an IndexError:
--> df.columns = df.iloc[0]
IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
Why would this work for my initial DataFrame, but give me errors on another of the same structure?

Comment: that error usually indicates that the row you're trying to access doesn't exist. you might consider asking a separate question because the question you asked and got an answer for here was about changing the column type to strings, so this new error is sort of unrelated to that. generally questions and answers on stackoverflow are meant to be for one type of error at a time to avoid having questions that ask too many things at once - hope that makes sense!